# Why isn't this audio file being read with sf_read_double?

Tags: c, audio, wav, libsndfile

I am trying to separate each subdivision of a drum sequence into a separate array inside a 2d array (rows for which subdivision, columns for data in each subdivision).
I determine how many samples per subdivision earlier in the code with user specifications on tempo and desired subdivision. I feel that I've a somewhat reasonable method for figuring out the size of the input file in samples (first section shown). 
My question is: as is, the sf_read_double while loop will not run. It is only when I multiply "buflen" by 2 (perhaps number of channels) that the loop runs. And when it does run 
 the the loop goes past the total number of samples calculated and results in a sug fault. What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
double framesArray[sfinfo.frames];
int numframes = (sizeof(framesArray)/sizeof(double));
int totalSamps = numframes * sfinfo.channels;
int totalSubdivisions = totalSamps / sampsPerSubdivision;
int buflen = sampsPerSubdivision;


int i;
double** choppeddata = (double**) malloc(totalSubdivisions * sizeof(double**));
for (i = 0; i < totalSubdivisions; i++)
    choppeddata[i] = (double*) malloc(buflen * sizeof(double*));
double* buffereddata = (double*) malloc(buflen * sizeof(double*));
double* outdata = (double*) malloc(totalSamps * sizeof(double*));

int j = 0, k = 0, sampnum = 0;
while ((readcount = sf_read_double (infile, buffereddata, buflen)))
{
    for (k = 0; k < buflen; k++)
    {
        choppeddata[j][k] = buffereddata[k];
        sampnum++;
    }

    j++;                                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `sampsPerSubdivision` be casted ? I suppose it has been declared as `int`. In which case you would need something like:

```
int totalSubdivisions = (int)(totalSamps / (double)sampsPerSubdivision);
```

So `totalSubdivisions` could be wrong... Anyway, this wouldn't explain why your `buflen` doesn't fit well the data to be read. My guess is that `sampsPerSubdivision` is not correct in the first place.

I couldn't say more. Hope this can help...

Comment: I'm somewhat of a novice programmer, so I guess I didn't know that and wouldn't know why I'd need to. 
In regards to the buffer, when I print out what the loop is doing, the buffer length works well.

Comment: The cast story has to do with integer division (if you do not cast into double). For the rest, you said that `as is, the sf_read_double while loop will not run. It is only when I multiply "buflen" by 2 (perhaps number of channels) that the loop runs` which made me deduce that `sf_read_double` was returning zero right at the beginning... Am I correct ?

Comment: Another thought: What happens if you read the samples one be one instead of by blocks of size `buflen`? Trying this would give you the real number of samples that are available (`sampnum`), and thus you would be able to make sure that this number is correct... I'm sorry but I'll have to leave. Keep me in the loop if you find out something new.

Comment: I messed around with casting a bit. I haven't gotten the other implementation to work yet. The reason I'm using the 2d array is because, as soon as I get this simplified code working, I would like to make the output random cuts of the input- essentially a drum mangler or cutter. 
If you're at all interested the code is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/dWZU9W92). I got it to print audio finally, but it's either chopping up the data causing it to stutter or playing it at twice the speed. 
As I mentioned, I'm a novice. This is just command line, I'll later learn about classes etc..